# Does Ethereum require miners to be a full nodes?

Tags: blockchain, mining

> Does Ethereum require a miner to be a full node?

It is necessary for miners to be full nodes, i.e., they store all blocks and the entire state of Ethereum? Or can miners also be light nodes which fetch needed blockchain parts?

Answer (score 2):

> It is necessary for miners to be full nodes, i.e., they store all blocks and the entire state of Ethereum?

Yes, it is necessary, they store all blocks and entire state. You run a full node (process the blockchain directly from the network) with 'geth' on one system.

> Or can miners also be light nodes which fetch needed blockchain parts?

No. But there is another solution. 
 You can join mining pool. You don't need to sync the blockchain - the mining pool provider will do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no,

Ethereum miners using a mining pool do not need to be running a full node.

Mining without a mining pool will require a fully synced node.